# Regular expression - allow space and any number of digits

Tags: java, regex

my valid string should be either `"1234" or " 1234"`

allow `one or zero space` at the beginning

then followed by any number of `digits` only

so what should be the regular expression for this ?

Comment: what about having " 1234aa" is this valid?

Comment: no , only digits , no alpabets...its a price field..

Comment: in that case check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
^ ?\d+$
```

which is easier to read like this:

```
^[ ]?\d+$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lT9iL6).

To test if you have a match, you can do (for instance):

```
if (subjectString.matches("[ ]?\\d+")) {
    // It matched!
    } 
else {  // nah, it didn't match...  }
```

Here you don't need the `^`  and `$` anchors, because the `matches` method looks for an exact match.

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string. Depending on the method used, these anchors may not be needed.
- `[ ]?` matches zero or one space. The brackets are not needed, but they make it easier to read. You can remove them. **Do not use `\s` there** as it also matches newlines and tabs.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: @AvinashRaj In Java: `\d` => Match a single character that is a “digit” (ASCII 0–9 only). The Unicode character thing you were linking to was from a C# question. :)

Comment: Little additional info: we don't need to explicitly add `^` and `$` anchors if we are using `matches` because this method checks if regex matches entire string anyway.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, you're right. Removed that from the code sample, will add explanation.

Comment: @AvinashRaj  Not by default, only with `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` or `(?U)` flag.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `\\s?\\d+`

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\s?\\d+", "1234"));  // true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\s?\\d+", " 1234"));  // true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\s?\\d+", "  1234"));  // false
```

`\s` denotes whitespaces and the `?` means zero or one occurence. The `\d` corresponds to a digit with `+` meaning at least one occurence.

In case only the space character is allowed (e.g. no tabs), use `( )?\\d+`

Comment: Yes indeed that's why I added the last sentence with only the space instead. The word "space" may sometimes be ambiguous in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex would be,

```
^\s?[0-9]+$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hY3mQ9)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the begining of the line.
- `\s?` A zero or one space is allowed.
- `[0-9]+` One or more numbers.
- `$`  Asserts that we are at the end of the line.

Comment: The `\s` is still a problem because it can match newlines, vertical tabs, tabs etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your input data must be only one space (not a whitespace), so the regex you need is `?\d+` (Note the space before "?").

On the other hand, if your input data must contain a whitespace, so you need to tweak the regex to:

```
\s?\d+
```

A whitespace character can be:

```
A space character
A tab character
A carriage return character
A new line character
A vertical tab character
A form feed character
```

As a note, if you need to discard all any character after your digits, for instace `1234fff` doesn't have to be matched, then you can fix your regex to: `\s?\d+\b` (this will make your regex to have a boundary).

Remember to escape backslashes in java code, so `\s?\d+` will be `\\s?\\d+`

Below you can find the regex for one space followed by only digits.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this: **"[\\d\\s]+"**